# Adding tvOS Parse SDK to existing iOS project

Tags: ios, parse-platform, tvos

Has anyone successfully added the Parse tvOS SDK to an existing iOS project with a separate tvOS target?

The iOS app already uses the Parse SDK.

I added a tvOS target to my project, added the `Bolts`, `Parse`, `SystemConfiguration`, and `libsqlite3.tbd` (got Parse & Bolts here: https://github.com/parseplatform/parse-sdk-ios-osx/releases/tag/1.11.0)

I can compile and run that target on the AppleTV simulator, but I get tons of warnings like this:

```
URGENT: building for tvOS simulator, but linking in object file
    (<path>Parse.framework/Parse(PFObject.o)) built for iOS. 
Note: This will be an error in the future
```

Also, calling `PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground` just hangs.

Not sure if what I'm trying to do just isn't possible of if I'm doing something stupid. Would be great to get this to work as there's lots of sharable code between the projects.

Comment: Looks like you're not alone: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/250

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I removed the iOS framework's path from the tvOS target's `Framework Search Paths` in build settings. The location of the iOS framework appeared first in the list of paths, which I guess hijacked the framework since the iOS/tvOS frameworks have the same name.

Sometimes you just have to take a break and then double check your assumptions.

Comment: where exactly? Could you please put a screen capture?